# Install custom ssl certificate in ddev container

Tags: ssl-certificate, ddev

I am currently trying to install a custom certification in a ddev container.
As stated in the documentation i copied the .crt and the .key file to /path-to-project/.ddev/custom_certs and renamed them according to the documentation.
After restarting the container it still uses the mkcert certificate it used before copying the new certificate.

Link to documentation https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/custom-tls-certificates/
The Certification is a wildcard certificate for all ddev.site domains.

Hope somebody can help
Kind regards
Franz

Comment: If you haven't already done so, please `ddev poweroff` and then `ddev start`. The doc should say that and doesn't. But the cert is picked up by ddev-router, so it needs to be restarted I think. Make sure that the cert is named correctly. You can `docker exec -it ddev-router bash` and examine the config in /etc/nginx/conf.d to see what cert is being configured. Also, please make sure you're using ddev v1.16+, preferably ddev v1.16.2.

Comment: It would help if you could show `ls -l .ddev/custom_certs` if you would as well... Remember that the name must be something like my.site.com.crt and my.site.com.key